# Dojo Custom Module Intellisense in VS 2013

Tags: javascript, dojo, intellisense, amd

So I'm using Visual studio 2013 and working with Dojo application (specifically ESRI's Javascript API). I've noticed that when I start "requiring" dojo-specific modules, I can see intellisense show up, no problem:

[image]

However, if I try creating/"defining" a custom module to use here, my intellisense goes away for everything:
[image]

Does anyone know how to get intellisense to work for both dojo modules and custom modules? The only way I can get custom modules to appear in intellisense is to reference require.intellisense.js in javascript file and exclude any dojo-specific modules. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following >>

1) Add dojo package via NuGet...

2) Click Tools > Options
Select Text > Javascript > IntelliSense > References

In 'Reference Groups', add to General and Implicit (Web) the following >>

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js
and/or
dojo.js local file

It worked for me...